# "screen" is losing umask setting

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, centos-6

I am using the `screen` tool quite a bit.

Recently I discovered that the `umask` within screen is different from what I am setting in my `.bashrc`.

```
$ screen -v
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

$ umask
0002

$ grep umask .bashrc
umask 0002

$ screen
$ umask
0022
```

What gives? How can I have screen retain the `umask`?

Comment: Hmmm ... https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1300700 ... noteworthy observation: in Ubuntu the umask doesn't change when I fire up screen; the shell running within screen inherits the umask from the parent shell.

Answer (score 1):

After my `umask` call in my `.bashrc`, I sourced `/etc/bashrc`.

This code caused my umask to get reset when `screen` or even `bash` was run after logging in:

```sh
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
   umask 002
else
   umask 022
fi
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the system-wide configs should always be read first (if at all). They set up defaults, which the user-specific configs can then customize and/or override. Your experience here demonstrates exactly why that order matters.